# Error con Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo un error grave con Firestore. Puedo crear colecciones y documentos, pero no me deja ver los documentos. No es una cuestión de código ya que esto me pasa en la misma consola de Firebase (web). Accedo con una cuenta de administrador y con buena conexión a Internet (veo otras web perfectamente y rápido). Accedo desde un Mac y he probado con diferentes navegadores dando el mismo error. Tampoco tengo ningún software que bloquee nada de tráfico. Adjunto las capturas de pantalla, **ya sé que dice que suele ser un problema de conexión pero no es el caso**. Muchas gracias, sois de mucha utilidad.

Console del navegador: 
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
- @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
E @ VM61:1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba lo que indican los compañeros de stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674482/firebase-firestore-firestore-5-0-4-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend

Comment: Tratándose de la consola misma de Firebase, es muy probable que el error se deba a un problema temporal de ellos mismos, o a que tu conexión, aunque sea rápida, esté muy ocupada ahora (por ejemplo si está en efecto una descarga gigante en algún dispositivo conectado a tu red, o el vecino te está robando el Wi-Fi :), etc), para descartar eso puedes entrar en el router para ver la actividad de tu internet. De todos modos, revisa el enlace de @Fergush, sobre todo lo relativo a algún firewall, antivirus, etc.

Comment: [Aquí se puede comprobar el estatus de Firebase en general](https://status.firebase.google.com), mientras que [aquí puedes comprobar el de Cloud Firestore](https://status.cloud.google.com). Actualmente no se presenta ningún problema. Entré a mi Cloud Firestore para ver si me pasaba lo mismo y funciona de maravilla, como siempre. Revisa por tanto lo que ocurre en tu red.

Comment: Me sucede lo mismo. Los documentos los he cargado desde https://app.flutterflow.io/ ¿tendrá algo que ver?, en Flutterflow los veo correctamente, pero desde la consola de Firebase/Firestore me muestra el error "No se pudieron cargar los documentos". Lo he probado en 3 días diferentes y consecutivos y error permanece. El status de Firebase y de Firestore es OK.
Agradezco su ayuda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas yo no se mucho pero fijate si no superaste el limite de los 51k de lectura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Gaston, fijate que estás contestando una pregunta formulada hace tres años, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!